# Finding the root for a reaction-diffusion equation system

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I would like to use [scipy.optimize.root](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root) in order to find the root of a two variable equation system, specifically the Gray-Scott model:

[image]

The variables `v` and `u` are 1D vectors. Is there a smarter way to do it rather than define a vector which is the concatenation of `v` and `u` and redefine the rhs of the equations accordingly?

Comment: "Is there a smarter say" shoud be "Is there a smarter way", right?

Could you clarify what you understand as the root of an reaction-diffusion equation system?

Comment: You'd like to try `scipy.optimize.root`, so go ahead and tell us where you get stuck!

Comment: By "the root", do you mean an equilibrium solution, where du/dt and dv/dt are 0 for all x?  What boundary conditions are you imposing?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - yes, I mean the equilibrium solution (or steady state solution). I imposed here periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: See eg https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#root-finding-for-large-problems

Comment: See @pv.'s link for a nice example.  A couple observations: (1) The constant values u=1, v=0 is a steady state for any parameter values. (2) Because you have periodic boundary conditions, the translation of any solution is also a solution, so if you find a nontrivial solution, it will actually be part of a one-parameter family of solutions.  That means you might have to deal with numerical issues related to that degeneracy.